# Quantified Boolean algebra written in Elementary Algebra

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, quantifiers

Propositional calculus can be "encoded" into elementary algebra using the formulas

$\neg x = 1-x$

$a \wedge b = ab$

Is there a way to encode the quantifiers $\forall$ and $\exists$ into elementary algebra in a similar way?

Comment: What is 'elementary algebra'?  You don't mean the algebra of natural numbers, correct?  But, what instead do you mean as 'elementary algebra'?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Elementary algebra is the name for the high school algebra that you encounter first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you code truth values as numbers in the standard way with $0$ representing falsehood and $1$ representing truth, then $\forall$ is $\inf$ and $\exists$ is $\sup$. More precisely, if we write $\phi \mapsto \phi^*$ for the translation of logical formulas into arithmetic expressions, then we have:

$$
\begin{align}
(\forall x\phi)^* &\equiv \inf\{x \mid \phi^* = 1\}\\
(\exists x\phi)^* &\equiv \sup\{x \mid \phi^* = 1\}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: is there any way to use variables and not functions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I've expanded my answer - does that help at all?

Comment: I was ideally looking for an answer that only uses arithmetic operations. Limits, infimum and supremum were outside what I wanted to consider. The infimum and supremum are equivalent to the infinity power means (min and max) which is closer to what I had in mind, but I didn’t want to use infinity either. I was hoping for something entirely numeric where the information is encoded into the reals. I suspect what I’m after isn’t possible.